# how to make a smooth plot in matlab

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I have about 100 data points which mostly satisfying a certain function (but some points are off). I would like to plot all those points in a smooth curve but the problem is the points are not uniformly distributed. So is that anyway to get the smooth curve? I am thinking to interpolate some points in between, but the only way that comes up to my mind is to linearly insert some artificial points between two data points. But that will show a pretty weird shape (like some sharp corner). So any better idea? Thanks.

Comment: Can you show your data and/or a graph of your raw data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know more or less what the actual curve should be, you can try to fit that curve to your points (e.g. using `polyfit`). Depending on how many points are off and how far, you can get by with least squares regression (which is fairly easy to get working). If you have too many outliers (or they are much too large/small), you can also try robust regression (e.g. least absolute deviation fitting) using the `robustfit` function.

If you can manually determine the outliers, you can also fit a curve through the other points to get better results or even use interpolation methods (e.g. `interp1` in MATLAB) on those points to get a smoother curve.

Comment: Yes, that's what I am thinking too, but the problem is there is not close form for the fitting function because that function is obtained by solving another set of equations numerically.

Comment: How about `spline()` to do piecewise curve fitting? It'll "smooth" out sequences of points that don't have a simple closed form underlying function.

Comment: To get rid of outliers, perhaps you could contsruct a minimum spanning tree http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree with weights proportional to distance and the clip off any nodes that only have one connection that is further than some threshhold distance away from the next node? Then you can use splines / other interpolation with smoother results.

Comment: @AndrewJanke: that would work, but I guess the same can be done with `interp1` with the `'spline'` parameter. Only drawback of both those methods is that you have to select the outliers first.

Answer (score 0):

If you know which function describes your data, robust fitting (using, e.g. [ROBUSTFIT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/robustfit.html), or the new convenient functions [LINEARMODEL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/linearmodel.fit.html) and [NONLINEARMODEL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/nonlinearmodel.fit.html) with the `robust` option) is a good way to go if there are outliers in your data.

If you don't know the function that describes your data, but want a smooth trendline that is little affected by outliers, [SMOOTHN](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25634-robust-spline-smoothing-for-1-d-to-n-d-data) from the File Exchange does an excellent job in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the use of smoothing splines? Like interpolating splines, but with the knot points and coefficients chosen to minimise a least-squares error function. There is an excellent implementation available from [Matlab central](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/13812-splinefit) which I have used successfully.